# Hide a gallery made with Galleria JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, galleria

I'm using Galleria to build my gallery in a website and it works fine but I want to take it to the next level.

I would like to know if someone here has tried to have an instance of Galleria in full screen mode only. I want a button to open a gallery in full screen mode when it's clicked and when the gallery is closed I would like to hide it. I tried to use jquery.hide() to hide the parent div used by galleria but first the gallery is still visible and second, it throws an error the second time I click the button to open it full screen.

Has someone succeded doing this?

If I didn't make myself clear enough please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// after click

```
$("#galleriaDiv").addClass("myClass");

.myClass { visibility: hidden; }
```

Comment: That worked but left the space the galleria div was using. Finally I ended up wrapping the galleria div in a parent div and gave the parent div the style width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden. I had to initialize galleria with a defined width and height too because it was throwing exceptions when I was defining the height only. The solution might be a little trashy but I'm running out of time and that's the only thing that worked as I really expected. Thank you for your help!